# Fix rust on front wheel

Tags: wheels, rust

How do I fix and prevent this rust on the front wheel?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Cleaning and rust protector/lubrication

Comment: Do you store this bike outside in the rain?  Or do you ride it and put it away wet ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rust shown is purely cosmetic.

Rust removal / Cleaning needs to be done with care. Even with the rubber seal, theres a chance of getting contamination into the bearings.  I would use a small wire brush and gently take the worst of off, then spray the surfaces with WD40, a silicon spray or other water repealant/lube spray. Not too much as you don't want it in the bearings. Oil or grease can also be used but be careful not to leave too much on - apply and wipe with cloth to remove excess.

If the bike is stored outside or in a damp location you may want give the metal surfaces a quick squirt regularly- especially after washing the bike.

Comment: I am very new to bicycle maintenance - when you mention "the bearings", could you explain where exactly those are? Thank you.

Comment: In the picture you see the axle, a lock nut and a rubber shroud. The bearings are hidden behind that. (Great picture in an answer to [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46138/can-hubs-last-forever)

Answer (score 1):

You could buy something like ACF-50. It isn't cheap, but if you put some on your bike every year or so with a cloth, it gets into the metal and helps protect it and one can should last quite a while.

Put it on your bike after you have washed and dried it.

By the way, please don't put oil, WD-40 or anything like this near your brakes - especially if you have discs.